# CEWP Disappears on Edit

Tags: 2013, content-editor-web-part, wiki, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

I've been using Wiki pages (by default) and adding CEWPs to them, and linking (text) script files to those from a site assets library to implement functionality.

However occasionally when I edit a page, the CEWP will disappear entirely from the page. At first I thought it was graphically gone only, but on save the page returned blank. No evidence there was ever a CEWP on the page.

Any idea why this would happen?

EDIT: After some tinkering, it seems to be linked to the Chrome type. Still no definitive info on why it's disappearing though.

Comment: which SharePoint version?

Comment: 2013 Enterprise

Comment: ok. No answer, but this happened to me too.